# My cocos2d project stopped compiling! Over 40 errors! What to do?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have had multiple snapshot and even reverting to them this thing just won't compile. It gives me over 40 errors! What can I do? I didn't change anything at all.
As I say, even reverting to old snapshot doesn't help and I have multiple of them.
I have cocos2d library with arc enabled from Steffen Itterheim.
Apparantely the problem is with cocos2d library itself. What can I do to fix this hell?

Edit: copying all my code into another project didn't help.  I am ready to cry now. I have spent so much time on this. ANd I am 99% positive there is no problem with my code, since I had multiple snapshots and none of them work.

What can be done in this situation?

Comment: Can you share some of the errors you're getting? Is there any pattern to them? Did you upgrade something outside your project (such as your development tools) at all? It's highly unlikely that *nothing* changed, since something must have triggered your errors.

Comment: @Tim any ideas with my answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix everything by copying  my files into new project. Hope that helps someone.
Actually I managed to reproduce a problem. When I change folder of my project everything stops working. How to fix that?
Even renaming of project folder produces same results.

Answer (score 2):

I think you renamed the wrong folder. If you use the ARC projects, there'll be two folders of the same name, one is a subfolder of the other:

[image]

You can rename or copy the first folder (close Xcode before doing so). But you **must not rename the subfolder**, ie the one that's in the same folder as the .xcodeproj. Likewise you **must not rename the .xcodeproj**.

The xcodeproj file is renamed automatically if you rename the project from within Xcode by selecting the first entry in the Project Navigator and renaming it like you would rename a file/folder in Finder (via delayed double-click).

If that's not what happened to you you need to be more specific about what you meant with "when I change folder of my project".

Comment: Actually I tried renaming the top folder and it still breaks it.