# Project compiles for simulator but gives 40 errors when compiling for device

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3

Yesterday I had a huge problem - suddenly my cocos2d project stopped compiling. You can read the story here: [My cocos2d project stopped compiling! Over 40 errors! What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746087/my-cocos2d-project-stopped-compiling-over-40-errors-what-to-do)

Apparently something changed the folder name and it was the reason. I have made a new project, copied my files into it, verified that everything worked, made a snapshot and zip backup and went to sleep. Now when I did a small change to code and compiled it for simulator it worked.
But when I tried to compile it for device I got same 40 errors. 
This is really killing me.

I use ARC-enabled cocos2d project.
If you want to check it out yourself here is the project - https://www.dropbox.com/s/eic1llpri6x6akt/BusterballBackupV1.0.zip

Restoring snapshot or from zip file didnt help either.

I think the problem might be with that:
When you look on the pane to the left of Xcode where you see your project layout there is a folder named Products. It contains two items in it - app itself and libcocos2d-library.a.
When I checked out fresh template they are black and have some strange path in the depth of xcode. But after I add files they go red and lose paths. What can be done about that? I cannot find that file (libcocos2d-library.a)

Comment: I am 99% sure that the problem is with cocos2d since all the problems come from compiling the library, not the project itself. What can be done about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the configuration of the static library target. The option "**Always Search User Paths**" should be set to NO. Here are the steps:

1. Choose the target cocos2d-library
2. In the right side, choose the Build Settings,
3. Find **Always Search User Paths** and set it to be **NO**

Build the project. It should be OK. The xCode version I used is Version 4.4 (4F250)

Comment: I'm fixing the project build settings now. I'll update the github repo  shortly.